# tkinter: displaying a square grid

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use tkinter to periodically refresh a square grid. Each square in the grid is painted a certain color (say obtained from a given function); in the center of each square, a smaller circle is drawn (the color is also obtained from a function).

If I have to do it from scratch, perhaps there's an example or a standard recipe I can use?

Comment: Are you having a problems drawing the grid with circles or refreshing it?

Comment: @martineau: I have a problem doing the drawing in a concise way. I think I misunderstand how tkinter is supposed to be used. I assume I won't have a problem with refresh but I haven't got to it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick hack showing how to draw a grid of rectangles and circles, and how to update the display once a second. If you've never programmed in tk before, it uses concepts that are no doubt foreign to you. You'll need to read up on canvas object ids and tags, as well as what the after command does.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
        self.rows = 100
        self.columns = 100
        self.cellwidth = 25
        self.cellheight = 25

        self.rect = {}
        self.oval = {}
        for column in range(20):
            for row in range(20):
                x1 = column*self.cellwidth
                y1 = row * self.cellheight
                x2 = x1 + self.cellwidth
                y2 = y1 + self.cellheight
                self.rect[row,column] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill="blue", tags="rect")
                self.oval[row,column] = self.canvas.create_oval(x1+2,y1+2,x2-2,y2-2, fill="blue", tags="oval")

        self.redraw(1000)

    def redraw(self, delay):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("rect", fill="blue")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("oval", fill="blue")
        for i in range(10):
            row = random.randint(0,19)
            col = random.randint(0,19)
            item_id = self.oval[row,col]
            self.canvas.itemconfig(item_id, fill="green")
        self.after(delay, lambda: self.redraw(delay))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a fully comprehensive documentation for tkinter? For example, I know that `create_oval` creates an oval inside the specified bounding rectangle, but I couldn't find the official description of this function anywhere.

Comment: @max: one of the better online resources for tkinter is http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ Tkinter is just a python wrapper around tk. The definitive documentation for tk is http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm, but it assumes you're using Tcl rather than python. It's only a small mental hurdle to translate the tcl code to python. Start with the efbot docs, and then if you need more specifics read the tcl documentation.

Comment: Can I do the `self.mainloop()` call from inside the `App.__init__` method instead of from the outside?

Comment: @max: I recommend you try it and see.